# How to set a cookie that counts the number of times a form has been sent per user?

Tags: php, html, css, csv

I'm having a problem with my PHP code, the cookie works, but I want to count how many times the same user(cookie) has sent a response.

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

- A feedback form with HTML (username, email, message)
- Styling with the side with CSS
- Processing of the form with PHP (output of a confirmation when the form has been submitted)
- Setting a cookie that counts the number of times a form has been sent per user.
- Storage of the content as a new line in a CSV file (format: "username", "email," message ")
- If a user has sent the form 3 times (see cookie) -> No storage and message to the user

Problem:

Setting a cookie that counts the number of times a form has been sent per user. If a user has sent the form 3 times (see cookie) it's not saved in CSV-File

```php
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $counter=0;
            setcookie("username",$_POST['username'],time()+60*60*24,"/");
            $conter = ++$_COOKIE['username']+1;
        }
     
         
     
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if ($counter<3) {
            $fp = fopen("feedback.csv", "a");
            fwrite($fp, "\"". $_POST["username"] . "\",\"" . $_POST["email"] . "\",\"" . $_POST["message"] . "\"\n");
            fclose($fp);
         }
        }
        ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Feedback</title>
    <style type="text/css">
     
    body{
    display: flex;
     
    min-height:100vh;
    background-image: url('bg.png');
    background-size:1800px;
    font-family: Didot, serif;
    }
    input{
      width: 100%;
      padding: 12px 20px;
      margin: 8px 0;
      border: none;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #008080;
    }
     
    }
    div{
    width: 500px;
    height: 700px;
    border-radius:18px;
    padding:10px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color:gold;
    top:100px;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #8ebf42;
    }
     
    }
    .header {
      padding: 60px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #1abc9c;
      color: white;
      font-size: 30px;
    }
     
    h1{
        text-align: center;
    }
    footer{
        bottom:0%;
        height:45px;
        position:absolute;
        color:white;
        background-color: black;
        width:100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .formp{
        color: green;
    }
     
    
    </style>
     
    
    </head>
     
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Feedbackformular</h1>
        </div>
        <div>
        <form target="_blank" method="post">
            
            <br>
            <label for="name">Username:</label>
            <input type="name" id="username" name="username" required>
            <br>    
            <br>
            <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="text">Feedback:</label>
            <input type="text" id="message" name="message" required>
     
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <br>
           
               <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
     
    
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
     if(isset( $_POST["submit"]))
     {
             echo "<p class='formp'>Es wurde gesendet!</p>";
    }
    ?>
     
    <footer>
      <p>&copy;</p></footer>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't see a counter value being set on the cookie, just the counter, and the counter is spelled wrong for the second instance.

Comment: So what do i have to do?Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your question relates to this portion of your code. You want to set a cookie that tracks the number of times a request was submitted to the server.

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $counter=0;
   setcookie("username",$_POST['username'],time()+60*60*24,"/");
   $conter = ++$_COOKIE['username']+1;
 }
```

**1: Inconsistent Variable Name.** 
You set `$counter` as your counter variable. Later you call it `$conter`. They should have the same variable name.

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $counter = 0;
   setcookie("username", $_POST['username'], time()+60*60*24,"/");
   $counter = ++$_COOKIE['username']+1;
 }
```

**2: Make Counter Global Variable.**
If you set the counter to equal 0 every time the user submits the form, and then add +1 to it later, the counter will always be a minimum value of 0 or a maximum value of 1. Instead, set the counter to equal 0 before submitting the value.

```
 $counter = 0;
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   setcookie("username", $_POST['username'], time()+60*60*24,"/");
   $counter= ++$_COOKIE['username']+1;
 }
```

**3: Set the Cookie** 
`setcookie(name, value, expire, path, ...)` is the `PHP` `setcookie` signature. I'm confused as to why you are setting the cookie as a username if you want to track the submission count. I could not find it being used anywhere else, so I'm assuming it's safe to set this as a count cookie instead of username. Add +1 to the `counter`, then insert the count as the value. The value will be stored as a string.

```
 $counter = '0';
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $counter = $counter + 1;
   setcookie("counter", $counter, time()+60*60*24,"/");
 }
```

**4: Initialize the counter with the cookie.** 
Check if the cookie exists, if it does with a value of 0 or greater then set the counter to equal the cookie value. If the cookie does not exist, set the counter to equal 0.

```
 $counter = '0';
 if( !isset($_COOKIE['counter']) && $_COOKIE['counter'] >= 0 ) {
   $counter = $_COOKIE['counter'];
 }

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $counter = $counter + 1;
   setcookie("counter", $counter, time()+60*60*24,"/");
 }
```

**5: Result** 
The following code will set the counter variable to 0. If a cookie counter exists, set the counter as the cookie value. This will allow it to retrieve the previously set counter even after the page refreshes or the user moves to a different page.

```
 // Set the counter to equal the current number of submissions.
 $counter = '0';
 if( !isset($_COOKIE['counter']) && $_COOKIE['counter'] >= 0 ) {
   $counter = $_COOKIE['counter'];
 }
```

This code will increase the counter and set the cookie every time the form submits using POST. The value can be retrieved later with `$counter` or from the counter cookie.

```
 // When the form is submitted, increase the counter and set the cookie.
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $counter = $counter + 1;
   setcookie("counter", $counter, time()+60*60*24,"/");
 }
```

Comment: Thank you!I'm new in PHP and my knowledge is low.Thanks for the improvments

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I did that.Thank you!